# What is the format specifier for string in arduino

Tags: arduino-ide, esp32

I have a string formattedDate.
When I am trying to give sprintf(payload,"{\"timestamp\":\"%s\",\"temperature\":%f,\"humidity\":%f}",formattedDate,t,h);
Its not printing the date and time.

Comment: Are you certain that `formattedDate` contains data?

Comment: is formattedDate a String? then use `formattedDate.c_str()`

Comment: When I use this I am able to print date and time --> Serial.println(formattedDate);

Comment: Actually, I am trying to send DHT11 data to AWS cloud. I am able to send temperature and humidity. I want time also to get imported for visualization. I am using NTP for date and time, so included the NTP libraries and this is working --> formattedDate = timeClient.getFormattedDate();
    Serial.println(formattedDate);  --> But i want it to print in JSON format. So I am printing like this sprintf(payload,"{\"timestamp\":%s,\"temperature\":%f,\"humidity\":%f}",formattedDate,t,h); But here i am unable to print date and time some random boxes and question marks are being printed.

Comment: println has a version for String sprintf doesn't

Comment: Can you please give me an idea to print the formatted date in JSON format so that I can visualise the data in quicksight

Comment: read my first comment